# Creating a time driven trigger that checks to see if a row has a certain value, if so add another value in same row but adjacent column (App Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title says, I'm trying to create an App Script with a time-driven trigger. Upon being triggered the script will check a specific sheet to see if a cell has a certain value. If so, add an 'X' to another column in that same spreadsheet.

I feel like I am close with this base code:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
// Trigger every 6 hours.
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(23)
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("F2:F").setValue('X'); {

// Loop over all triggers and delete them
var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) 
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);

}
}
```

But am very much a novice with App Scripts. From my understanding, this script is just missing the functionality to add 'X' to only rows that meet a certain condition.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi Matthew, 
It's nice to have added your code, but you should state what type of error you are encountering. I can see that on your code there may be several issues so I don't know what is blocking, example:
- on the line 9 (where you write the X) there looks to be an extra { at the end of the line
-last action you do is deleting all your trigger so the trigger you setup first will be deleted

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Harold. My code now is what Cooper has attached within his answer below. The issue here is that it's filling the entire column with the set value, not just cells where the adjacent cell has the value from the if statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

This function only allows you to create one trigger for a given handlerfunction.

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "myFunction").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().atHour(23).everyDays(1).create();
  }
}
```

The function

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter sheet name");
  const rg =sh.getRange("Enter Cell Range")
  if (rg.getValue() == "The Value") {
    rg.offset(0, "offset to column").setValue("X")
  }
}
```

Comment: Should the "function to run" be myFunction or createTimeDrivenTriggers?

Comment: myfunction.....

Comment: Okay then this is the error returned: "ReferenceError: Spreadsheet is not defined
myFunction @ Untitled.gs:7"

Comment: Try it again...

Comment: No luck. Same error.

Comment: It cannot be the same error because there is no Spreadsheet  term any longer.  You must have done something wrong

Comment: Okay well, I've placed this code into another script editor (Different Google Account) and it starts and executes just fine now. I've removed the function createTimeDrivenTriggers, so that I can test the function. And after doing that nothing happens, no errors though.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do?  I don't have anything of your data

Comment: I also don't have any idea what you final version looks like.  Do you know how to debug code?

Comment: Did you check executions?

Comment: This is my final code: function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rg = sh.getRange("C:C")
  if (rg.getValue() == 1) {
    rg.offset(0, 2).setValue('X')
  }
}

Comment: No, I don't know how to debug but when I click the debug button it says there are no breakpoints.

Comment: If you don't select break points the pressing the debug button is essentially the same as pressing run.  But you can do a lot of debugging with just console.log and Logger.log as well as using the executions.    Without any addition debugging information I can't really help you.

Comment: Okay, good news. The script functions with no breakpoints and fills the offset column with a desired set value. The problem is that it's filling the entire column with the set value, not just cells where the adjacent cell has the value from the if statement. Any ideas on how to specify which cells should be filled with set values? Thanks.

Comment: First you must specify which cellls they are.  Right now the one that gets set is "offset to colum" of the current cell

Comment: They're cells 3 columns to the right, same row of the cell that has value being checked by if statement.

Comment: I figure a line of code needs to be added that specifically places the .setValue parameter in that cell. Do you know what that line of code is?

Comment: Yes it's this one `rg.offset(0, "offset to column").setValue("X")` which is the one that's already there